# How do I filter really tiny columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-filter

Sometimes in my filter views, whenever I have really small columns, the triangle icon to filter them does not show up at all. I'm able to temporarily resolve this by expanding the column, but it's really annoying to have to do this every time I want to filter by that column. Is there another way to filter the column without that temporary solution?

EDIT: I'm on a MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to see filter triangle like in **B1**, select it by clicking on **B1** and then simply press:

- Windows: **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** **+** **<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** **+** **<kbd>`R`</kbd>**
- Mac: **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** **+** **<kbd>`⌘`</kbd>** **+** **<kbd>`R`</kbd>**

  [image: 0]

Comment: I tried both Ctrl + Left Alt + R and Cmd + Left Alt + R, and neither one worked.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: ctrl+leftalt+r is called **Open drop-down menu on filtered cell** - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en and it works with both filters (green & black)

Comment: also when pressing ctrl+leftalt+r you need to be in that cell where is that triangle otherwise it won't work. referencing the image from the posted answer - it would work only if A1 or B1 is highlighted/selected.

Comment: It's Ctrl + ⌘ + R on Mac. I got it to show up now. Thank you.